# Find distance to the ocean/ Intersection of vectors

Tags: matlab, gps, maps, distance

I am interested in the W, NW, SW distances to ocean for many points in the continental USA. For testing purposes, I'm looping through a 1/8th deg dem at 500 m (32x32 pixels) [GMTED2010](http://topotools.cr.usgs.gov/GMTED_viewer/) and a vertical coastline. I looked around this site and consequently implemented the pdist2 function however I'm not getting what I expect. So my first question is if I'm conceptually wrong and second is my pdist2 implementation incorrect? I'm also open to other solutions.

I expect to see the same pattern for all 3 directions given the directional constraint. The western most column of pixels will have the same distance, the next column will be the same, etc so when I plot a 32x32 matrix of `dlong` using `imagesc` I get a gradient low to high, left to right.

```
%**************
%For those truly interested, you can download the DEM and get Z and R accordingly:
[Z120,R120]=geotiffread('~/path/to/tif/GMTED2010N30W120_150/30n120w_20101117_gmted_mea150.tif');
[Z150,R150]=geotiffread('~/path/to/tif/GMTED2010N30W150_150/30n150w_20101117_gmted_mea150.tif');
Z=[Z150 Z120];
R=R120;
Z=Z(:,6001:4800+7200); %crop Z from -100 to -125. use latlon2pix to confirm between sub-z and z
R.Lonlim=[-125, -100]; 
R.RasterSize=size(Z);
clear Z150 Z120 R150 R120

%******* HERE STARTS THE ALGORITHM
%coastline (ultimately will be from the coast library)
latlim=[0.25:.25:60];
lonlim=ones(length(latlim),1)*-110

%variables r and c are the row and column indices for the point I'm interested in. r and c are relative to a DEM for the entire western USA so a point in Colorado is something like 2370,4350.
rstart=2370;
cstart=4350;

for r=2370:2370+31
    for c=4350:4350+31   
        %rows and cols are the vectors in the NW direction from point r,c.
        %in the SW direction, rows=r+[1:min(r,c)-1]. cols is the same.
        %W direction, rows=ones(r,1)*r; cols=c-[1:c-1];
        rows= r-[1:min(r,c)-1];
        cols= c-[1:min(r,c)-1];

        %Use referencing object R for DEM Z of the western USA to convert rows and cols to lat and long.
        [NWcoord(:,1) NWcoord(:,2)]=pix2latlon(R,rows,cols);

        %use pdist2 to find the shortest distance between any two points in the two vectors
        [D,i]=pdist2(lonlim,NWcoord(:,2),'euclidean','smallest',1);
        [~, mi]=min(D);

        sta.NWcoast=[latlim(i(mi)) lonlim(i(mi))];
        dlong(r-rstart+1,c-cstart+1)=distance(lat,long,latlim(i(mi)),lonlim(i(mi))); %great arc distance on earth's surface. radians
    end
end
```

Comment: Why do you need a DEM (Digital Elevation Model) to find the distance (air distance?) to the coast polygon? The DEM contains Height Data. For what do you need them?

Comment: Good question. This routine is part of a series of variables I am deriving from the DEM. I need a suite of variables for each pixel in a subset of the DEM. Because it's part of the rest of the function, I was using the size of the  DEM as a reference for the size of the NWcoord vector. This is partly because I won't know how long the NWcoord vector needs to be to ensure it crosses the coast vector and I know the DEM covers the full domain I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works if you have a referencing object R. Thanks to @AlexWein for the azimuth idea. The reason for the striping in the previously posted picture was the scale of the coastal vector.  Notice I'm using 0.0042 deg increments (same as dem resolution). The 5 stripes were indicating that I was only finding the distance using 5 coastal coord points and the stepped stripes happened because I was bouncing from nearest point below to nearest point above and back again.

```
    latlim=[0.25:.0042:60];
    lonlim=ones(length(latlim),1)*-110

for r=1:32
    for c=1:32

    [lat long]=pix2latlon(R,r,c)
[d, az]=distance(lat,long,latlim,lonlim);

[~, azi]=min(abs(az-270));
sta_o.Wd2O=d(azi);
sta_o.Waz=az(azi);

[~, azi]=min(abs(az-315));
sta_o.NWd2O=d(azi);
sta_o.NWaz=az(azi);

[~, azi]=min(abs(az-225));
sta_o.SWd2O=d(azi);
sta_o.SWaz=az(azi);

    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

Solve it whitout *DEM*.

1) You have given a location loc  with latidude and longitude in decimal degrees WGS84.
2) You have given the coats line polygon in WGS84, to.

Now to find the East West Distance from loc to polygon:
You want to find the crossing of the latitude value of loc with the border poly (east of current position):

Start at the beginning of border poly point 0:
Find the line where `border[i].lat<= loc.lat and border[i+1] > loc.lat AND border[i].longitude >= loc.longitude`. If you found the line, make a linear interpolation between (i, and i+1) to find the exact (lat/long) intersection.

Now you have the intersection to the ocean:
Calculate the distance loc -> intersection with `haversine` formula.

(Once this works you can later decide if you want to speed up with a binary search)

Same  you do for the other 3 direction, with exchange lat/long and greater/smaller

**For NW and others:**
Run along the ocean border points and calculate the bearing from loc to border point(search for aviation formulas or greater circle bearing calculations)

store the line /or two points where bearing steps over the 315 degrees.
This line then intersects the 315°, Theretically ther ecould be more than one such line 
store all such lines, and take the one whoch is closest to location (

Now interpolate both points to get exact cut with 315.

Update: [Bearing formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: I need it constrained to the 3 directions, how does this take that into account? also, what is p?

Comment: Updated p, I showed it for Direction Point to Ocean in East direction. Try to understand how it works, then the othe rthree direction: to N, to S, to W, are analog.

Comment: I understand how it works. The cardinal directions are easy because you only need to compare one variable.  This approach works for W but I really need help with NW and SW (315 deg and 225 deg) for which it does not work as far as I can tell. `loc` changes based on how far away you are from the coast.

Comment: Updates now it works for all angles, it runs along the border with a bearing to formula (greater circle) which stores when the bearing is found.

Comment: Here is a [picture](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5962491/d2O.png) of my output. Units are degrees. West looks right but I expected NW and SW to look similar.  I can't decide if it's right...why the striations?  Code for NWd2O looks as follows:                                                           `for i=length(latlim):-1:1
 if azimuth(lat,long,latlim(i),lonlim(i)) >= 314.5 && azimuth(lat,long,latlim(i),lonlim(i))<315.5
  [sta_o.NWd2O sta_o.NWaz]=distance(lat,long,latlim(i),lonlim(i));
  break
 end
end`

Comment: your code is not correct. it can overjump the 315.5. better detect  the first border point that overjumped the 315.0. and the point before. write a junit test first, with a border line of a regular 6-gon

Comment: I can see how testing for azimuth(...) <= 315 is more robust but it gives the same results. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: The points is not 315.5 or 315, your for loop is to simple, you must track the overstepping of the 315 degree, with oild State , newState. JUst write a unit test case wit a regualr 8 - gon and debug, then you see why it does not work.

Comment: I don't need a for loop actually but I don't understand what you mean the for loop is too simple either.                                                                 `[d, az]=distance(lat,long,latlim,lonlim);
    [~, azi]=min(abs(az-270));                                     sta_o.Wd2O=d(azi);
    sta_o.Waz=az(azi);`   And this is already a test case. my coast vector latlim/lonlim is a straight line at -110 and the area of interest is only 32x32 pixels.

Comment: I submitted an answer below that solves it. No loops required.